# How do I calculate the correct CGRect origin on a scaled UIView subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, scale

I need to calculate the visible CGRect of a UIView subview, in the coordinates of the original view.  I've got it working if the scale is 1, but if one of the superviews or the view itself is scaled (pinch), the visible CGRect origin is offset slightly.

This works when the scale of the views is 1 or the view is a subview of the root view:

```
// return the part of the passed view that is visible
// TODO:  figure out why result origin is wrong for scaled subviews
//
- (CGRect)getVisibleRect:(UIView *)view {
    // get the root view controller (and it's view is vc.view)
    UIViewController *vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;

    // get the view's frame in the root view's coordinate system
    CGRect frame = [vc.view convertRect:view.frame fromView:view.superview];

    // get the intersection of the root view bounds and the passed view frame
    CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(vc.view.bounds, frame);

    // adjust the intersection coordinates thru any nested views
    UIView *loopView = view;
    do {
        intersection = [loopView convertRect:intersection fromView:loopView.superview];

        loopView = loopView.superview;
    } while (loopView != vc.view);

    return intersection; // may be same as the original view frame
}
```

When a subview is scaled, the size of the resultant view is correct, but the origin is offset by a small amount.  It appears that the `convertRect` does not calculate the origin properly for scaled subviews.

I tried adjusting the origin relative to the X/Y transform scale but I could not get the calculation correct.  Perhaps someone can help?

To save time, here is a complete test ViewController.m, where a box with an X is drawn on the visible part of the views - just create a reset button in the Main.storyboard and connect it to the `reset` method:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  VisibleViewDemo
//
//  Copyright © 2018 ByteSlinger. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

CG_INLINE void drawLine(UIView *view,CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2, UIColor *color, NSString *layerName) {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:point1];
    [path addLineToPoint:point2];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.name = layerName;

    [view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}

CG_INLINE void removeShapeLayers(UIView *view,NSString *layerName) {
    if (view.layer.sublayers.count > 0) {
        for (CALayer *layer in [view.layer.sublayers copy]) {
            if ([layer.name isEqualToString:layerName]) {
                [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
            }
        }
    }
}

CG_INLINE void drawXBox(UIView *view, CGRect rect,UIColor *color) {
    NSString *layerName = @"xbox";

    removeShapeLayers(view, layerName);

    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);

    drawLine(view,topLeft,topRight,color,layerName);
    drawLine(view,topRight,bottomRight,color,layerName);
    drawLine(view,topLeft,bottomLeft,color,layerName);
    drawLine(view,bottomLeft,bottomRight,color,layerName);
    drawLine(view,topLeft,bottomRight,color,layerName);
    drawLine(view,topRight,bottomLeft,color,layerName);
}

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

UIView *view1;
UIView *view2;
UIView *view3;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 4;

    view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, width, height)];
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor;
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self addGestures:view1];

    view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2 + height + 16, width, height)];
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
    [self addGestures:view2];

    view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, width / 2, height / 2)];
    view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor.blueColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    [view1 addSubview:view3];       // this one will behave differently
    [self addGestures:view3];
}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self checkOnScreen:view1];
    [self checkOnScreen:view2];
    [self checkOnScreen:view3];
}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    view1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    view2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    view3.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)addGestures:(UIView *)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];
}

// return the part of the passed view that is visible
- (CGRect)getVisibleRect:(UIView *)view {
    // get the root view controller (and it's view is vc.view)
    UIViewController *vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;

    // get the view's frame in the root view's coordinate system
    CGRect frame = [vc.view convertRect:view.frame fromView:view.superview];

    // get the intersection of the root view bounds and the passed view frame
    CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(vc.view.bounds, frame);

    // adjust the intersection coordinates thru any nested views
    UIView *loopView = view;
    do {
        intersection = [loopView convertRect:intersection fromView:loopView.superview];

        loopView = loopView.superview;
    } while (loopView != vc.view);

    return intersection; // may be same as the original view
}

- (void)checkOnScreen:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect visibleRect = [self getVisibleRect:view];

    if (CGRectEqualToRect(visibleRect, CGRectNull)) {
        visibleRect = CGRectZero;
    }

    drawXBox(view,visibleRect,UIColor.blackColor);
}

//
// Pinch (resize) an image on the ViewController View
//
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    static CGAffineTransform initialTransform;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];

        initialTransform = recognizer.view.transform;
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    } else {
        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(initialTransform,recognizer.scale,recognizer.scale);

        [self checkOnScreen:recognizer.view];

        [self.view setNeedsLayout]; // update subviews
    }
}

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    static CGAffineTransform initialTransform;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];

        initialTransform = recognizer.view.transform;
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    } else {
        //get the translation amount in x,y
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];

        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(initialTransform,translation.x,translation.y);

        [self checkOnScreen:recognizer.view];

        [self.view setNeedsLayout]; // update subviews
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You should take view's bounds property instead of frame. Bounds are not affected by scale transform.

Comment: @kirander - I thought so too at first, but the bounds origin and size never change, only the transform info.  So the convertRect/CGRectIntersection trick won't work.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to know the real visible `frame` of a view that is somehow derived from `bounds`+`center`+`transform` and calculate everything else from that, instead of the ordinary `frame` value. This means you'll also have to recreate `convertRect:fromView:` to be based on that. I always sidestepped the problem by using `transform` only for short animations where such calculations are not necessary. Thinking about coding such a `-getVisibleRect:` method makes me want to run away screaming ;)

## What is a `frame`?

The `frame` property is derived from `center` and `bounds`.

**Example:**

- `center` is `(60,50)`
- `bounds` is `(0,0,100,100)`
- => `frame` is `(10,0,100,100)`

Now you change the `frame` to `(10,20,100,100)`. Because the size of the view did not change, this results only in a change to the `center`. The new `center` is now `(60,70)`.

## How about `transform`?

Say you now transform the view, by scaling it to 50%.

=> the view has now half the size than before, while still keeping the same center. It looks like the new frame is `(35,45,50,50)`. However the real result is:

- `center` is still `(60,50)`: this is expected
- `bounds` is still `(0,0,100,100)`: this should be expected too
- `frame` is still `(10,20,100,100)`: **this is somewhat counterintuitive**

`frame` is a calculated property, and it doesn't care at all about the current `transform`. This means that the value of the `frame` is meaningless whenever `transform` is not the identity transform. This is even [documented behaviour](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame). Apple calls the value of `frame` to be "undefined" in this case.

## Consequences

This has the additional consequences that methods such as `convertRect:fromView:` do not work properly when there are non-standard transforms involved. This is because all these methods rely on either `frame` or `bounds` of views, and they break as soon as there are transforms involved.

## What can be done?

Say you have three views:

- view1 (no transform)

  - view2 (scale transform 50%)

    - view3 (no transform)

and you want to know the coordinates of view3 from the point of view of view1.

From the point of view of view2, view3 has frame `view3.frame`. Easy.
From the point of view of view1, view2 has not frame `view2.frame`, but the visible frame is a rectangle with size `view2.bounds/2` and center `view2.center`.

To get this right you need some basic linear algebra (with matrix multiplications). (And don't forget the [anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint)..)

I hope it helps..

## What can be done for real?

In your question you said that there is an offset. Maybe you can just calculate the error now? The error should be something like 0.5 * (1-scale) * (bounds.size) . If you can calculate the error, you can subtract it and call it a day :)

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the help.  You really put some time into your answer.  I am so very close but I suspect that what you mention regarding that `convertRect ` may just not work with a transformed view.  I did try several variations to adjust the resultant origin, including the one similar to what you mention, but I just couldn't get it right.  I even tried to apply the transforms for each view in the hierarchy, but still no werky.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Michael for putting in so much effort in his answer.  It didn't solve the problem but it made me think some more and try some other things.

And voila, I tried something that I'm certain I had done before, but this time I started with my latest code. It turns out a simple solution did the trick.  The builtin `UIView` `convertRect:fromView` and `convertRect:toView` worked as expected when used together.

I apologize to anyone that has spent time on this.  I'm humbled in my foolishness and how much time I have spent on this.  I must have made a mistake somewhere when I tried this before because it didn't work.  But this works very well now:

```
// return the part of the passed view that is visible
- (CGRect)getVisibleRect:(UIView *)view {
    // get the root view controller (and it's view is vc.view)
    UIViewController *vc = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;

    // get the view's frame in the root view's coordinate system
    CGRect rootRect = [vc.view convertRect:view.frame fromView:view.superview];

    // get the intersection of the root view bounds and the passed view frame
    CGRect rootVisible = CGRectIntersection(vc.view.bounds, rootRect);

    // convert the rect back to the initial view's coordinate system
    CGRect visible = [view convertRect:rootVisible fromView:vc.view];

    return visible; // may be same as the original view frame
}
```

If someone uses the `Viewcontroller.m` from my question, just replace the getVisibleRect method with this one and it will work very nicely.

NOTE:  I tried rotating the view and the visible rect is rotated too because I displayed it on the view itself.  I guess I could reverse whatever the view rotation is on the shape layers, but that's for another day!